# MySQL object browser is absent

Tags: mysql, ide, mysql-workbench

I believe that I successfully installed `MySQL` from the web, but my sql web layout is very different from the normal layout as it has no object browser, also home page too seem different. In addition I have `WAMP server` installed on my laptop, is this the reason? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

I am attaching pictures of both the pages.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Look at the sidebar, specifically the headings. Near **MANAGEMENT** there's a little button. This is to switch between combined (stacked) and tabbed mode for this sidebar. At the moment the stacked mode is active by default and you cannot see the schema part because it is hidden behind the **Information** pane. There's a splitter between the 2 parts, so you can make the **Information** pane smaller, but I think you are better off by switching to tabbed mode, as this makes working there a lot simpler.